# Как получить картинки по средствам библиотеки Jsoup в Java по протоколу https?

Tags: java, android, парсер, jsoup

Весь вопрос в заголовке, я использовал метод [по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10482239/3789850), но он прекрасно работает с http протоколом, а для https не хочет ничего находить, я пытался скачать картинки с Twitter по средством данной библиотеки, заходил на страницу с браузера и просматривал коды элементов, ручным поиском удавалось находить ссылки на картинки, но библиотека не справляется, подскажите, что не так

Мой код:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.by/search?q=images&biw=1680&bih=913&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIhMivvNX2xwIVBlksCh0JUAbr").get();

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");

                for(Element e : doc.select("img")){
                    stringBuilder.append(e.attr("src")+"\n");
                    l++;
                }
```

Если нету возможности через данную библиотеку, то прошу подсказать другой способ или самому свой парсер воять?

Comment: Данный код работает, просто нужно было учитывать перенаправление  со странички

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл в чём была проблема, дело было в том, что по переходу по ссылке происходило перенаправление, а т.к. я это не учитывал, то и картинок не было видно, [данный код](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864575/3789850) мне помог

Comment: обновил свой комментарий

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле не везде так просто парсется, как в примере. У меня есть три приложения в маркете - это распаршеные сайты, ну так вот, именно doc.select прокатывал очень редко. Получалось везде что- то такого плана:

```
html.getElementsByClass("comment").get(i).getElementsByClass("datacom").get(0).text();
```

Вообщем бывают очень сложные запросы до нужного итема. Попробуйте под дебагом сначала добраться до одного элемента, если получится, то уже циклом по всем.

Comment: Спасибо, завтра обязательно попробую и отпишусь, но метод указанный мной отлично работает с http протоколами, по крайней мере в VK выводил ссылки правильно

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле не везде так просто парсется, как в примере. У меня есть три приложения в маркете - это распаршеные сайты, ну так вот, именно doc.select прокатывал очень редко. Получалось везде что- то такого плана:

```
html.getElementsByClass("comment").get(i).getElementsByClass("datacom").get(0).text();
```

Вообщем бывают очень сложные запросы до нужного итема. Попробуйте под дебагом сначала добраться до одного элемента, если получится, то уже циклом по всем.

**Update**

ради интереса решил тоже посмотреть как с https быть. В итоге у меня вышло вот так.

```
class HTTPRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.google.by/search?q=images&biw=1680&bih=913&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIhMivvNX2xwIVBlksCh0JUAbr");

                HttpResponse response;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if (entity != null) {

                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                        String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                        instream.close();

                        final Document html = Jsoup.parse(result);

                        ArrayList<String> images = PageLoader.getImages(html);


                    }

                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    ignored.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Достать картинки вашем способом удалось. =) `html.select("img").attr("src")`

Comment: Я себя не хвалю, но на данный момент лучше способа не нашёл, а данный способ довольно хороший и в проверенных мною случаях выдаёт то, что мне необходимо, он даже отлично показывает наличие картинок закодированных в Base64, впоследствии чего картинку довольно легко получить раскодировав её, в обще я доволен результатом, надеюсь это поможет другим

Comment: Кстати, вы используете довольно громоздкий код для этих целей, по средствам Jsoup нету необходимости самому создавать потоки и т.п. код умещается в пару строк

Comment: Cогласен, что получилось громоздко, но коротким ходом у меня не получилось задекодить массив байт, который я получал на выходе. Пожалуй ваше решение действительно лучше. Возьму на заметку)

Comment: В этом и прикол "Супа", можно не возиться с потоками и сделать это в пару строк